# This array should be mutable, but I keep getting an error saying it's a let constant... even though it's declared with var?

Tags: arrays, swift, variables, constants

I have an array that is declared with `var` and initialized as being full of zeroes. But when I try changing an element in the array, I get an error saying:

> Left side of mutating operator isn't mutable: 'inArray' is a 'let' constant

This makes no sense to me as I declared the array with `var` and at no point did I make it a constant. Here's my code:

```
var pickedCount = Array(repeating: 0, count: sprinkleList.count)
func addOneToPickedCount(addOneTo element: Int, _ inArray: Array<Int>){
    inArray[element] += 1 //Left side of mutating operator isn't mutable:'inArray' is a 'let' constant
}
```

Comment: Function parameters are equivalent to `let`. `inArray` is a copy of the passed in array and `inArray` is a constant.

Comment: You can get the effect you want by making `inArray` an `inout` variable: `func addOneToPickedCount(addOneTo element: Int, _ inArray: inout [Int])` and then call it like this: `addOneToPickedCount(addOneTo: 1, &pickedCount)`